# proc sql adding minutes column tother for a running total

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I am new to proc sql.

I have a column made up of minutes...
example:

```
15:5
14:5
8:5
13:6
```

I would like to add the minutes together, create a running total in hrs:minutes:seconds
example:

```
2:23:23
```

I am lost.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: The values you've posted don't look like minutes. I would expect `15:50` as an example. What have you tried so far?

Comment: that how i have found the in the table i have to work from.

Comment: Are they character or numeric?

Comment: That's the format, what's the type.

Answer (score 3):

If you have true time variable then you can add them using a retain. PROC SQL is not a good way to do this.

```
 data want;
 set have;
 retain running_total;
 running_total+time;
 format running_total time.;
 run;
```

Note that a retain is not required in the code above because the sum statement (without equals) has an implied retain.

Comment: You should elaborate on why proc sql is not a good way to do this.